# When to declare a local variable as static in C?

Tags: c, static

I recently learned about storage classes in C. In particular I was fascinated by the `static` storage class. Coming from Haskell I eschew the concept of passing an output buffer to a function to obtain a result. For example consider the following `readfile` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readfile(const char * filename, char * contents, size_t size) {
    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fread(contents, size, 1, file);
    contents[size] = 0;
    fclose(file);
}
```

There are several reasons I don't like code like this:

1. The use of `void` as a return type irks me. I don't know why. It just does.
2. Passing an output buffer to a function seems unnatural. Mutable state is error-prone.
3. You shouldn't have to pass the number of bytes to read as an input parameter to the function.
4. You need to create a buffer manually and predict the size of the file.

Due to these problems I rewrote the above code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

char * readfile(const char * filename) {
    FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    static char * contents;
    contents = malloc(size + 1);
    fread(contents, size, 1, file);
    fclose(file);

    contents[size] = 0;
    return contents;
}
```

Now all you need to do to read the contents of a file is pass the filename to `readfile`. It allocates space for the contents of the file and returns a pointer to the newly created buffer. The only bookkeeping you need to do is to `free` the buffer once you're done with it.

As you can see in the above code I have declared `contents` as `static` so that there's only one instance of that variable, and so that you can return it without the compiler giving you a warning. In my opinion this is a cleaner solution than using global variables.

Nevertheless, I am skeptical about using `static` in production code: partly because I am afraid of mutable state coupled with shared variables, and partly because this is the first time I am using it. What are the potential risks of using `static` as demonstrated?

For example could the above code give erroneous results when you're reading two files concurrently? How do I address these problems without reverting back to C-style code (e.g. passing an output buffer to the function, etc.)

Comment: What warning do you get when you remove `static`? I don't get any. The only situation I can think the compiler would warn you is if it were a non-static *array* you were returning; but it's not an array, it's a pointer.

Comment: `#include <malloc.h>`? Maybe you meant `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: You don't understand the difference between arrays and pointers. If `contents` was an auto (i. e. non-`static`) array, and you returned it, then you would have invoked undefined behavior because the array would have been converted to a pointer, but it would already have been out of scope. But since you are allocating a buffer dynamically, you don't need `static`: the value of the pointer is copied upon returning from the function.

Comment: @ajay I think `stdlib.h` itself includes `malloc.h`. Why bother including additional things you don't need?

Comment: Also, you coming from a functional language heavily shows itself :P you are mythically afraid of state, mutability and a function which is not returning values. Don't do that. C is a procedural and imperative programming language. Don't try to program in Haskell when you are programming in C.

Comment: @icktoofay Indeed, I don't get any errors either. Well that simplifies my code. I feel light headed now.

Comment: Your new function is not thread safe and may create memory leak, if caller doesn't release the memory returned by function.

Comment: @AaditMShah `<malloc.h>` is not standard. `<stdlib.h>` is, and it's `<stdlib.h>` that declares `malloc()`.

Comment: @AlexFarber I understand the problem of memory leaks if the caller doesn't `free` the dynamically allocated memory. However I can't descry how the second function is thread-unsafe. Would you elucidate your comment please?

Comment: @AaditMShah The approach demonostrated above is very bad. 1) causes you memory leaks (there is no VM or GC to collect up unused memory in C) 2) inefficient (static arrays are much faster than dynamic allocation 3) All C functions use buffer output to read, this is the language style

Comment: @AaditMShah regarding your last line, you should write only C-style code in C :)

Comment: @Desolator what? That's just BS. Your first and second statements are absolutely wrong. 1.) Causes memory leaks? OP **explicitly** mentioned that he **knows** that he has to `free()` the buffer. 2.) Inefficient? First of all, who does even worry about efficiency without profiling/benchmarking? It's just downright irrelevant. And static buffers aren't "faster" **at all,** that assertion of yours is **just false.** But anyway, even if it was: I/O is already orders of magnitude slower than memory access, so the difference is entirely insignificant.

Comment: The function declaration of fread as fallow

size_t fread ( void * ptr, size_t size, size_t count, FILE * stream );

it's not necessary to use the static. If you are declare with static compiler only consider as   char * contents;

Comment: Just think about two instances of this function, running in different threads, and modifying the same static variable `contents`. Function is always thread safe, if it works only with its parameters and local non-static variables. First version is OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost never want to declare a local variable as `static` in C.

Making a variable `static` essentially makes it a global variable whose name is not accessible outside of that function. As you're likely well-aware, global variables can be problematic: if you ran `readfile` from two different threads, you could have the first call `malloc` and store the result into `contents`, the second thread call `malloc` and store *its* result into `contents`, and then the first thread `fread` into the `contents` the second thread allocated, which could result in a buffer overrun if the file being read on the second thread was smaller and is undesirable in any case.

The reason you might have been tempted into using `static` was that `contents` was previously an array. If so, the compiler would have rightly warned that you can't return that to the caller: it will decompose to a pointer, but as soon as the function returns, the local array variable is destroyed and the pointer becomes invalid. Declaring it as `static` makes it valid to return, as because it's a global variable, it won't be destroyed when the function exits and the pointer will remain valid. There are still problems if you use it with threads, though.

The only time you might want to use `static` is if you've got some constant data only used within a function. For example:

```
static const int some_integers[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

Then you can save some stack space.

Lest I forget to mention your specific code, removing `static` makes it work as desired. If this code were to be used in real life, I'd make sure to add some error checking, as almost all of the functions you call can fail and will signal that only through a return value.

Answer (score 0):

There are also POSIX functions like `stat(2)` and `fstat(2)` that allow you to find out the exact size of the file. You can use this to allocate the buffer and read the data all in one go.

In the case that your file is rather large you could also use the `mmap(2)` system call or the `CreateFileMapping` and `MapViewOfFile` to have the operating system do much of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: What if the file size is 2 GB ??

Comment: The stat/fstat use an off_t to track the file size. On many systems this is a 64-bit integer. 2GB is not an issue there.

Comment: @Desolator Well, what? Nothing special.

Comment: Yes it can allocate it on x64, but "filling out" the memory whithout a real purpuse. Also, too much time to allocate this huge space

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair point. In that case I recommend mapping the file using mmap or CreateFileMapping/MapViewOfFile on Windows.

Comment: @jduck Please edit your answer to remove the downvote

Answer (score 0):

Using static in this case will effective make the variable's memory get stored in the global data segment of process memory. However, it will only have local scope (only this function sees it). Since you are likely to be tracking the pointer some other way (the return value) it's unnecessary to use this method and wastes a pointer worth of global data memory (probably not a big deal).